# What access is necessary to update a CloudFormation stack with nested stacks

Tags: aws-cloudformation, nested-stack

Using nested stacks is a [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#nested) in AWS CloudFormation, and indeed they solve many problems (code reuse, stack limits, etc).

It's also generally a good idea to do any sort of updates with the minimal access necessary for that update (using the RoleARN of the UpdateStack command). I can't seem to find any documentation on exactly IAM access is necessary to update a stack that has nested stacks.

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61896385/1207489), a stack update will always get the template for the nested stack again.

1. (in addition to any rights necessary for the resources that are to be changed),`s3:GetObject` (or `s3:GetObjectVersion` if a versioned url is used) is necessary for the location where the template for the nested stack is hosted.
2. In addition (and I'm not sure why), an `iam:GetRole` is necessary for role to self-inspect (so the `Resource` should be the Arn of the role itself).